# Long-term stay visa requirement for Germany when holding a Dutch Residence Permit

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, germany

I currently have a Netherlands Residence Permit valid for 2years and I am currently studying at Netherlands. My next year of studies is at Berlin.
I will be going back to India during this summer break.

1. Is it possible to travel from India to Germany with the Netherlands Residence permit? Or do i need to get a Schengen D type visa for Germany?
2. I will be applying a German Residence Permit after I reach Berlin. For this I would need a valid passport, Proof of Finance and Health insurance. So if option 1 is possible I do not need to apply a Schengen D type visa for Germany at all?

Answer (score 4):

Your Netherlands residence permit allows *short* visits to other Schengen states, including but not limited to transit.

For a year of studies in Germany, you will need a German D permit. You should apply for it in advance, not just on arrival, even if the Dutch D permit would allow you to enter Germany. The processing might take some time.
But questions regarding the German D permit are best asked on Expatriates SE.

Comment: (+1) Some people (e.g. US citizens) may apply for a residence permit from within Germany. The OP could apply from the Netherlands.

Comment: @Relaxed, I'd think he *must* reply from his *current* place of residence, i.e. the Netherlands, unless that is a special hardship.

Comment: Indeed but often applying from your country of citizenship is not too difficult in practice and it would not be difficult for the OP to argue that he or she is a resident of India if he went back there after finishing his or her studies in the Netherlands. OTOH, it might not be completely obvious that applying from the Netherlands is possible, which is why I thought it was useful to point this out.